# onclick по ссылке и event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

Предположим, есть вот такая структура:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">пункт 1</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">пункт 2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-list mainlist">
        <li>
            <a href="#">подпункт 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-list sublist">
                <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">подпункт 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-list sublist">
                <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">222</a></li>
                ...
```

Почему вот такой код отменяет переход по ссылке для `<a>` второго уровня (в  `.sublist` )?

```
window.onload = function() {
  var levelOne = document.querySelectorAll('.mainlist li');
  for (var x = 0; x < levelOne.length; x++) {
    if (levelOne[x].childElementCount === 2) {  /* find all 'li' with submenu */
      levelOne[x].onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();   /* prevent goto url of <a> if there is sublist */
      }
```

А вот такой не отменяет? То бишь, работает только на первый уровень.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var levelOne = document.querySelectorAll('.mainlist li a');
  for (var x = 0; x < levelOne.length; x++) {
    if (levelOne[x].parentElement.childElementCount === 2) {    /* find all 'li' with submenu */
      levelOne[x].onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();   /* prevent goto url of <a> if there is sublist */
      }
```

---

Я понимаю свой код в первом случае (при `.querySelectorAll('.mainlist li')`) таким образом: обработчик `click` пропускает "погружение" и отслеживает "всплытие", поэтому после нажатия мышкой на `a` должен произойти переход по ссылке, а после этого событие всплывёт к `li` и там уже должен сработать `preventDefault`. Так что отмена перехода по ссылке, вроде как, вообще не должна происходить.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае ты затрагиваешь li, поэтому оно ловит событие и отменяет последующие, а так как "a" находится непосредственно внутри этого элемента, то до него это событие не доходит.

Answer (score 0):

Тут получается как бы помимо всплытия ещё и "погружение". Простите за аналогию.
У вас не получается провалится событием `click` через `li` к `a`, так как `li` перехватывает и отменяет событие.

Но это вам уже сказали и без меня

Comment: `preventDefault` не отменяет всплытие.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что событие от вложенных уровней всплывает и обрабатывается на `li`.

Во втором случае ссылка не является родительским элементом для других ссылок.

Comment: выходит, что, пройдя первый уровень и увидев, что есть второй уровень, отмена события произойдёт не только на том элементе, где выла обнаружена вложеность, но и на его наследниках?